# How to merge two arrays based on the property value in react with ES6

Tags: arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, array-merge

I have two arrays:

```
 a = [{"sourceId": "1", "targetId": "2", "name": "heats air"} , 
      {"sourceId": "3", "targetId": "4", "name": "power"}]

 b = [{"name": "Hair Dryer", "id": "1"}, 
      {"name": "Heating System", "id": "2"}, 
      {"name": "Mains", "id": "3"}, 
      {"name": "Blower", "id": "4"}]
```

How do I get the output like this:

```
[{"sourceId": "1", "targetId": "2", "name": "heats air", "from": "Hair Dryer", "to": "Heating System"}, 
 {"sourceId": "3", "targetId": "4", "name": "power","from": "Mains", "to": "Blower"]
```

I want to merge them based on the property values: the keys "sourceId" and "targetId" of array a should correspond to the key "id" of array b. If a sourceId is matched with an id, add the value of the name with key "from" to the object in array a;   If a targetId is matched with an id, add the value of the name with key "to" to the item in array a. Also,I am wondering whether I can do this without using lodash. (using ES6)

Comment: It is unclear what the merging algorithm is supposed to be as the objects that get merged have no common properties.  How do you determine what gets merged with what?  Please describe "in words" what the merging algorithm is.  And, how do you determine what `from` and `to` should be set to?

Comment: The keys "sourceId" and "targetId" of array a should correspond to the key "id" of array b.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the merging algorithm to your question.  Also describe how `from` and `to` are supposed to be set.  Comments should not be used for required information - that information should be added to the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `b` to a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of `id` to `name` using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). Then [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) `a` to the required form using [Object#assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), and the `bMap`:

```js
const a = [{"sourceId":"1","targetId":"2","name":"heats air"},{"sourceId":"3","targetId":"4","name":"power"}];

const b = [{"name":"Hair Dryer","id":"1"},{"name":"Heating System","id":"2"},{"name":"Mains","id":"3"},{"name":"Blower","id":"4"}];

const bMap = b.reduce((map, item) => map.set(item.id, item.name), new Map);

const result = a.map((item) => (Object.assign({
  from: bMap.get(item.sourceId),
  to: bMap.get(item.targetId)
}, item)));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```js
 const a = [{"sourceId": "1", "targetId": "2", "name": "heats air"} , 
      {"sourceId": "3", "targetId": "4", "name": "power"}]

 const b = [{"name": "Hair Dryer", "id": "1"}, 
      {"name": "Heating System", "id": "2"}, 
      {"name": "Mains", "id": "3"}, 
      {"name": "Blower", "id": "4"}]
      
 const result = a.reduce((arr, curr) => {
  const from = b.filter(bObj => {
   return bObj.id === curr.sourceId;
  })[0]
  const to = b.filter(bObj => {
   return bObj.id === curr.targetId;
  })[0];
  arr.push({ ...curr, from: from.name, to: to.name });
  return arr;
 }, []);
 
 console.log(result);
```